# Unable to connect to data source using 'sa' user name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Trying to debug an issue with a data source, I am currently getting this error:

[image]

The error is occurring in my DataSet2, on this particular Dataset:

[image]

Looking at the logs, I see this:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.DataSetExecutionException: The execution failed for the shared data set 'DataSet2'.
>
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset ''.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'facilities'.`

My next step to figure this out is to open this DataSet and confirm the query. When I try to `Edit in Report Builder` and it prompts me for my credentials. In this case, I am trying to use the `sa` user, but it is telling me that my credentials are invalid.

[image]

I've confirmed on the actual SQL Server that the credentials are correct.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What data source is the data set connected to? Are you sure it is connecting to the server you think it is? This error message would indicate that a table (likely a table but could be an object) doesn’t exist in the database the data set is using as its connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look related to the username SA.  The error suggests that the Dataset2 does not have the facilities table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is in the query. You may be trying to get data from other tables or other servers where you do not have the rights granted.

This is my personal experience